# debugging steps taking 10+ seconds even for System.out.println(variable); statements

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm having Mac with 16 GB RAM and latest IntelliJ IDE version 2022.3.2

While debugging all the steps are taking 10+ seconds, even simple statements like below

```
System.out.println(variable);
```

Is this bug with IntelliJ or some setting needs to be enabled ?

Comment: Does it also still slow in a Hello world project? Also check the guide here to improve the debugger performance: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544799-Java-slow-performance-or-hangups-when-starting-debugger-and-stepping

Comment: Below accepted answer has solved the problem. Thanks for sharing link anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Vikramvi

Is the application running properly in Run mode?

If yes, Try the following.

1. Open Settings, then open the collapse of Debugger Settings.
2. Inside that open the collapse of Data Views then click Java.
3. Try disabling "Enable alternate view for Collections classes" and "Enable 'toString()' object view" checkboxes.

Comment: you're the BOSS, thanks a ton for quick help.